# Multi UID in one SQL [DBMS] Table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Can any body tell me if the following is possible in one SQL table.

[Code Allocation Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhQqq.png)

Basically when a new record is created, by populating the first 3 columns, the reference in column 4 is then generated, but the number is specific to the Project and Type fields and increments by 1 each time (multiple UID in one Table). So if some one generates another TEQ Document against Project 21345, for example, it remember the last number was 3 and allocates 4, as shown in the picture.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What output are you trying to get? Provide some example

Comment: Hi the output is really the calculated field HDL Reference, there are other columns with associated attributes but I have removed them from the picture to simplify. The table is then used as a reference for an excel based document management system. The challenge is the numbering that starts at 1 for each combination of [Project] and [Type], and increments within that combination .

Comment: It is possible to store more than one value in field, but it is not really a good idea to do it. You should normalise and store your data in 2 tables and use a view or query to generate the required output.